# Field extensions equal

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, transcendence-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $F(x_1,x_2)$ be a finite seperable extension. Let $t_1,t_2$ be algebraically independent over $F$. Let $u=t_1x_1+t_2x_2$. Prove that $F(t_1,t_2,u)=F(t_1,t_2,x_1,x_2)$.

One containment is clear however I am not able to prove other containment.

Comment: It is enough to show that $K := F(t_1,t_2,u) \cap F^{sep}$ and $L:=F(t_1,t_2,x_1,x_2) \cap F^{sep}$ are equal. I tried to show that $K$ and $L$ are fixed by the same automorphism but I'm stuck :/

(Of course, $L=F(x_1,x_2)$ ...)

Comment: I am not getting any bright ideas. I don't know whether the proof involves some advanced stuff like regular extensions which I don't know.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using some arguments of transcendence degree but they are not that rigid. I haven't made any significant progress towards solution in any case.

Comment: Lüroth's theorem?